# Why doesn't testing exit status work when output is redirected?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, exit-code

I have been testing bash and found the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ `which pacman` ]] && echo pacman
[[ `which apt-get` ]] && echo apt-get
```

It will test what package manager is installed and echo it.

On some systems, a failed `which` command prints the error to `stderr`.  I want to suppress all output from the `which` command.

So I came up with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ `which pacman >/dev/null 2>&1` ]] && echo pacman
[[ `which apt-get >/dev/null 2>&1` ]] && echo apt-get
```

But this doesn't output anything.  When I run each command on the command line like this:

```
which pacman >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo $?
```

On a system with `pacman`, it prints `0` which it should.  The `&&` also proves that the previous command succeeded.

So why doesn't the redirection code work like it does on the command line?  What can I add to the script to make it work?

This is really confusing to me, as I have never had this type of problem before.  Usually, any command that works on the command line should also work in a bash script, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[[ ... ]]` without a specified test runs `[[ -n ... ]]`. In this case, it tests whether the captured output is non-empty. But if you redirect everything to /dev/null, the output is indeed empty!

You don't need to capture the output. `which` should already return a non-zero status when it cannot find the file to execute.

```
which pacman &> /dev/null && echo pacman
```

Comment: Ty for this understanding.